# Video html5 com anuncio

Tags: html5, vídeo, anúncio

Estou com um código pra colocar anuncio em video 5 segundos, mas não consigo coloca-lo em cima do video no canto direito, posso até usar css mas com full screen ele não funciona, alguém tem uma idéia

```js
var media = document.getElementById("media");

function secToStr( sec_num ) {
    sec_num = Math.floor( sec_num );
    var horas   = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
    var minutos = Math.floor((sec_num - (horas * 3600)) / 60);
    var segundos = sec_num - (horas * 3600) - (minutos * 60);

    if (segundos < 10) {segundos = segundos;}

 switch(segundos) {
     case 0: segundos = 5; break;
     case 1: segundos = 4; break;
     case 2: segundos = 3; break;
     case 3: segundos = 2; break;
     case 4: segundos = 1; break;
     case 5: segundos = 0; break;
 }
     if (segundos>5) segundos = 0;

    return segundos;
}


media.ontimeupdate = function() {
 segundos = secToStr(media.currentTime);    

    if (media.duration == media.currentTime) { 
     media.src= "http://rodrigoti.com.br/novo/2.mp4";
     media.play();
     $("button").hide();
    };

    if (segundos < 1) { 
     segundos = "";
     $("button").html("Pular");
     $("button").click(function(){   
      media.src= "http://rodrigoti.com.br/novo/2.mp4";
      media.play();
     $("button").hide();      
  });
    }else{
     $("button").html("Pular video em "+segundos+ " segundos" );
      
    }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Pular video em 5 segundos</button> <br>
<video id="media" autoplay width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="http://rodrigoti.com.br/novo/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: Ué...e como é feito no youtube?

Comment: acho que no próprio vídeo. Se fosse diferente já estaria na boca dos programadores e achariamos o script facilmente

Comment: voce executou o exemplo? é no proprio video, mas vou tentar colocar uma div por cima mesmo e colocar a função e desabilitar o fullscreen, so habilito o fullscreen após anuncio

Comment: Tem como já abrir o vídeo em tela cheia com um html por cima.

Comment: veja kithomepage.com/sos/tester.htm. clica na imagem ela some. Se não clicar ela some depois de alguns segundos

Comment: mais elaborado, http://kithomepage.com/sos/tester3.htm

Comment: Consegui...muito obrigado, coloquei o html por cima e funcionou, ficou semelhante ao do youtube :)

Comment: Você fez igual ao meu exemplo, já abrindo em tela cheia ou descobriu como colocar o html clicando no botão full screen?